# dependency issue while installing phpmyadmin on nginx webserver

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I tried to find a solution for this problem for a long time but I cannot find it. Maybe you can help me.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system and want to use it for web development using nginx. Nginx is installed and works properly, but I am not able to install phpmyadmin via the command

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

because of this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libapache2-mod-php5filter but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cgi but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
                       php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
```

I guess my PPA's are not reliable.

Greetings!

Comment: stupid question are php and mysql installed and running/working?